# Adding new rows to dataframe in a loop with Python

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, addition, rows

I would like to keep adding rows to a dataframe in a for loop.
My current code is:

```
df1 = DataFrame()  #empty df
for i, row in df2.iterrows():
    str1 = ... ... #obtain the str1 via some string manipulation with row
    val1 = ... ... #obtain the val1 via some numerical calculation with row
    df1 = concat(df1, DataFrame([{'col1': str1, 'col2': val1}]))
```

The above code does not work as I keep getting the error:

> *UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df1' referenced before assignment*

May I know what should be the right way to do this?

Comment: That code would not give that error.

Comment: You're right, I had simplify the problem and didn't realise it affected the error.

Comment: The original code resides within a function, that's why the error.

Comment: I got it out of the function and it works now (although i changed to using append instead of concat as it gave another error).<BR>Thanks Daniel